# How can I count the number of times a string occurs in a pandas column based on categories of strings in another data frame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.
In `df1['sdk']`, this column has `sdks` associated with each unique app id. `df2` has two columns, `sdk_category`, `sdk_names`.

For every SDK category, multiple SDK names have been listed.

The desired output is to get additional columns in df1 `for each sdk category` with a count of `how many sdks from that category were used in that unique app`. I am new to python data frames, I would very much appreciate any and all help. I am trying to illustrate my problem below as best I can:

**data1:**

| id | name | sdks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | a,b |
| 2 | y | b,d |
| 3 | z | a,b,c |

**data2:**

| sdsk_category | sdks |
| --- | --- |
| cat1 | a,b,c |
| cat2 | b,d |
| cat3 | d,a |

**result:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DaVV.png]

Thank you in advance!! I am willing to correct/improve the information provided to help you help me if required.

Comment: Don't post image. Copy paste the dataframe as a text form.

Comment: use: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Comment: Whenever you have confidential data try to create either dummy or modify the data a bit. You don't need to post the whole data. Only some sample will be enough to write a logical.code. share the traceback of the error.

Comment: Please check the output of df3 which is after `df1.assign....`

Comment: Very helpful, I found the error for this line of code, changed for my context: df3['co'] = df3.apply(lambda x:  sum((Counter(x['sdks_x'].replace(',',"")) & Counter(x['sdks_y'].replace(',',""))).values()), axis=1)#.s1m(axis=1). The df3 merge went well, I added the error trace to the original question

Comment: Solved now? If it's solved close the question by accepting the answer :)

Comment: I'm sorry, my code still doesn't work, the sdsk_x is not resolved. I just posted the error trace. It's the counting stage that is stuck.

Comment: show me the output for this: `df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), how='outer', on='key').drop('key',axis=1)`

Comment: I gave you the answer accoring to the sample data you provided. To make it to work in your case you have to modify the code. Your columns are different in original data. So why are using this column name which I have mentioned.  The column that you have in your original data, mention those. Logic will be the same.

Comment: Thanks, I cannot share each column I believe. Shall I close this thread and post separately a fresh question? Your solution has helped me merge the two datafarmes, but the counter is not running on the sdk column, mayb because of some datatype incompatibility. I will try to post the next example as close to original data as possible. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

This is the worst solution I can think of:

```
from collections import Counter
df3 = df1.assign(key=1).merge(df2.assign(key=1), how='outer', on='key').drop('key',axis=1)

df3['co'] = df3.apply(lambda x:  sum((Counter(x['sdks_x'].replace(',',"")) & Counter(x['sdks_y'].replace(',',""))).values()), axis=1)#.s1m(axis=1)

df3 = df3.groupby(['id', 'name', 'sdks_x', 'sdsk_category']).mean().squeeze().unstack().reset_index()
```

---

df3:

```
sdsk_category   id  name    sdks_x  cat1    cat2    cat3
0               1   x       a,b     2       1       1
1               2   y       b,d     1       2       1
2               3   z       a,b,c   3       1       1
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your useful suggestions on posting the question correctly.I  wasn't sure (I am still not sure) to what extent I can openly share the data even for my own problem. I have tried the coed you recommend with modifications,  I am getting the following error: KeyError: 'sdks_x'.  Shoudl I share my modified code to get better help?