# Sort pandas list type column values based on another list type column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df 
col1        col2                 col3
A       ['p', 'q', 'r']          ['x', 'r', 'p']
B       ['x', 'y']               ['y']
C       ['t', 'u', 'p']          ['u', 'p', 'x', 't']
D       ['a', 'b']               ['x', 'y']
```

Now I want to sort values(lists) of col2 based on the col3 sequence so the final dataframe would look like,

```
 df
 
 col1        col2                 col3
 A       ['r','p', 'q']           ['x', 'r', 'p']
 B       ['y', 'x']               ['y']
 C       ['u', 'p','t']           ['u', 'p', 'x', 't']
 D       ['a', 'b']               ['x', 'y']
```

I could do this using a for loop and comparing two lists, but it will take more time to execute, looking for some pandas shortcuts to do it more efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

One idea is use cutom function with list comprehensions for test membership:

```
def f(x):
    a = x['col2']
    b = x['col3']
    yes = [x for x in b if x in a]
    no =  [x for x in a if x not in out]

    return yes + no
    
    

df['col2'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
  col1       col2          col3
0    A  [r, p, q]     [x, r, p]
1    B     [y, x]           [y]
2    C  [u, p, t]  [u, p, x, t]
3    D     [a, b]        [x, y]
```

Pandas solution:

```
df['col2'] = (df['col3'].explode().reset_index()
                        .merge(df['col2'].explode().reset_index(), 
                               left_on=['index','col3'],
                               right_on=['index','col2'],
                               how='outer')
                       .dropna(subset=['col2'])
                       .groupby('index')['col2']
                       .agg(list))
print (df)
  col1       col2          col3
0    A  [r, p, q]     [x, r, p]
1    B     [y, x]           [y]
2    C  [u, p, t]  [u, p, x, t]
3    D     [a, b]        [x, y]
```

Comment: Hello jazzy: do you have answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66327954/6660373 was just wondering there must be some better solutions using pandas function(melt/pivot etc).

Comment: @Pygirl - Here working with lists, it pandas not like very much ;) So pure python is here best (in my opinion).First idea for pandas solution is impossible, then try explode and merge and it working. Edited answer.

Comment: I was asking for above-posted link (question) :P.  But thanks for giving one more approach will get to learn something new.